# ArrayFormula Auto-Increment

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Никак не могу понять, как именно работает нижеприведенная формула в Google Spreadsheets:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)))
```

Мне не ясно, почему **ROW(B2:B)** (1ый аргумнет) вообще работает. Первым аргументом же должен идти диапозон, функция ROW возвращает текущий номер строки, так почему он отрабатывает по-другому и возвращает как будто диапозон, состоящий из номеров строк?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Странное поведение...

В `Excel` такая конструкция не сработает, т.к. `COUNTIF` первым аргументом воспринимает только диапазон листа, а `ROW(B2:B9)` - это диапазон номеров строк (от 2 до 9).

В `Google`-таблице, похоже, интереснее, но в справке разъяснения не нашел. Возможно, незадокументированная возможность, и такое предположение:

т.к. `ROW` - строка, то `ROW(B2:B9)` (диапазон чисел) в первом аргументе функции `COUNTIF` восприниматься как диапазон листа и ошибка не возникает. Тогда понятна логика работы функции.

Но сама запись странная... Если хотели пронумеровать строки, то достаточно

```
=ArrayFormula(ROW(B2:B)-1)
```

Comment: да, конструкция очень странная, на работе у коллеги с ней столкнулся, никак не могу понять, почему она работает. Нигде нет информации. Другими способами, конечно, легко и понятно сделать, но мне просто хотелось именно в этом разобраться. Спасибо за помощь)